# vbs script running with keyboard and mouse lock

Tags: vbscript

The script I created below opens a number of virtual machines whilst the script is running the local machine's keyboard and mouse is locked via the shortkeys entry of the script CTRL ALT + F. When the script is finished I would like the keyboard and mouse to unlock using the same function.

Note that even though the keyboard is locked the hot keys  to unlock the keyboard and mouse are still active these are CTRL ALT + F.

The script runs perfectly but does not unlock the keyboard and mouse, please can anyone see any issues with this script?

```
Dim shell
Set shell = wscript.CreateObject("Shell.Application")
    set x = CreateObject("Wscript.shell")
    x.sendkeys("^%{f}")
shell.Open "C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VirtualBox.exe"
WScript.Sleep 3000
shell.Open 
"\\leeds.smoothwall.net\DFS\homefolder\steve.newton\Documents\Local 
Automation scripts\VBS files\Paths\NetworkGuardian.lnk"
WScript.Sleep 120000
shell.Open 
"\\leeds.smoothwall.net\DFS\homefolder\steve.newton\Documents\Local 
Automation scripts\VBS files\Paths\IE11 - Win10 Admin.lnk"
WScript.Sleep 20000
shell.Open 
"\\leeds.smoothwall.net\DFS\homefolder\steve.newton\Documents\Local 
Automation scripts\VBS files\Paths\IE11 - Win10.lnk"
WScript.Sleep 20000
Set shell = wscript.CreateObject("Shell.Application")
    set x = CreateObject("Wscript.shell")
    x.sendkeys("^%{f}")
WScript.Sleep 2000
    MsgBox "Automation Startup complete"
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution, when the virtual machines started they automatically sent the user controls to the active windows, I turned this option off and now the script works perfectly.